# Does synchronized block cause all write cache to flush?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, jls

I am interested in how `synchronized` works in sense how/when it flushes writes from local caches. Lets imagine I have following code:

```
class Scratch1 {
  int counter = 0;
  Scratch1() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    counter += 5;
    counter += 5;
    // Does this cause to flush possibly cached value written by main thread even if it locks
    // on totally unrelated object and the write doesnt happen inside the sync block?
    synchronized (String.class) {}
    Executors.newCachedThreadPool().submit(() -> {
      for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        counter += 5;
      }
      synchronized (Integer.class) {}
    }).get();
    System.out.println(counter);
  }
}
```

```
class Scratch2 {
  int counter = 0;
  Scratch2() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    // Or is this only possible working way how flush written data.
    synchronized (String.class) {
      counter += 5;
      counter += 5;
    }
    Executors.newCachedThreadPool().submit(() -> {
      synchronized (Integer.class) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
          counter += 5;
        }
      }
    }).get();
    System.out.println(counter);
  }
}
```

```
class Scratch3 {
  volatile int counter = 0;
  Scratch3() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    counter += 5;
    counter += 5;
    Executors.newCachedThreadPool().submit(() -> {
      for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        counter += 5;
      }
    }).get();
    System.out.println(counter);
  }
}
```

I have several questions:

1. Does all three examples share same "thread-safety" level (taking into account specifics like first write is done by one thread and second write is done after first one (is it?) and by another thread) i.e. "is it guaranteed that 5010 is printed"?
2. Is there performance difference (at least theoretical) in "operating" outside a synchronized block or working with non-volatile properties (I would expect volatile access to be slower as [this post confirms](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/volatile.html#performance-considerations-of-volatile)) but in case of synchronized block is the "flushing" price paid only when crossing synchronized start/end or is there also difference while inside the block?

Comment: There is no "cache" in the Java Language Specification (JLS). Cache is an implementation detail. The "[Memory Model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4)" section of the JLS explains in detail what you should expect when your threads share data. One rule of thumb you can derive from it is; Anything that thread A does before it leaves a `synchronized` block is guaranteed to become visible to thread B by the time thread B enters a block that is `synchronized` on the same object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am interested in how synchronized works in sense how/when it flushes writes from local caches.

Actually, `synchronized` doesn't flush writes from local caches. It just acts as if it did so.

> Does all three examples share same "thread-safety" level (taking into account specifics like first write is done by one thread and second write is done after first one (is it?) and by another thread) i.e. "is it guaranteed that 10 is printed"?

They all provide slightly different forms of thread safety. None of them are really safe if other threads are accessing the object at the same time. For example, another thread accessing `counter` would have to hold both the `String.class` and the `Integer.class` locks to ensure ensure it didn't see `counter` during an operation. The third one uses increment operations that aren't atomic, though it's safe if no other thread tries to modify `counter`.

> Is there performance difference (at least theoretical) in "operating" outside a synchronized block or working with non-volatile properties (I would expect volatile access to be slower as this post confirms) but in case of synchronized block is the "flushing" price paid only when crossing synchronized start/end or is there also difference while inside the block?

No difference. Entering a `synchronized` block has a cost because the lock has to be acquired and some optimizations have to disabled across the entry point. Exiting the block has similar costs.

Inside the block, there are no costs because the safety is provided by the programmer ensuring they don't allow any thread to modify the object unless it holds the same lock and no two threads can hold the same lock at the same time. Generally speaking, code may not even know whether or not it's inside one or more `synchronized` blocks because it can be deep down the call tree.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the part "synchronized doesn't flush writes". What does the flush then?

I mean am I guaranteed that once synchronized block is exited all writes up to that point done by current thread are flushed to main memory regardless those happend inside or before the block?

According to your exaplanation there would no difference in performance so probably no reason to such thing (except one level of indentation less :)).

Comment: @svobol13 By flushing do you mean updating the counter variable outside of the thread cache?

Comment: @MatthewKerian by flushing I refer to writing thread cache into RAM so it is possible for other threads to get fresh data.

Comment: @svobol13 You are not guaranteed that writes are flushed to main memory and, in practice, they are not flushed to main memory. That's great because main memory is very slow. Your code, however, acts as if they were flushed to main memory. There really is no "thread cache" to write into RAM on the systems you're probably working on (and the caches that are present are made coherent across threads in hardware anyway). Don't confuse what effects you have to get with what it takes to get those effects.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I see, so I should consider some "highly optimized dark magic" (keeping track of who has copy and to whom we have to supply new data after synchronization right?) to happen behind the scenes so my other threads can see up-to-date value without even writing data to main memory. And that is why you pointed out to my incorrect wording "flushing cache" in your answer, right?

Comment: @svobol13 Yes, exactly. It's helpful to understand what these things do by imagining a simple CPU that requires simple operations and imagining that those operations are performed. But in a real system, it's much more like dark magic. To understand when and where particular things are needed without having to understand CPU-specific dark magic, it's helpful to imagine a generic simple CPU that's not much like any real world CPU. On that imaginary CPU, everything flushes to main memory on entry and exit of synchronized blocks. Within them, the lock itself provides the protection.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'm confused what you're saying. What do you mean there's no 'thread cache'? Each specific thread doesn't get a cache, but threads will often write into CPU cache as opposed to RAM to save time. I think what he's asking is what events force a write to the main program memory instead of a local cache

Comment: @MatthewKerian Right, and the answer is nothing forces a write to main memory. On modern CPUs that you're likely to use, those caches are made coherent by hardware so there's no need to flush them to main memory. But it's easier to understand when you need things like `synchronized` by thinking about an imaginary CPU that had caches that needed to be flushed. No reason to think about complex dark magic in modern CPUs just to understand the semantics of a high-level language like Java!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz How are they equalized on a hardware level?

Comment: @MatthewKerian Punch "MESI protocol" into your favorite search engine. But I warn you, this rabbit hole gets pretty deep. Modern CPUs are *very* complex beasts. (Hence the reason we use imaginary simplified CPUs to teach synchronization concepts.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Read through the wiki article. Seems pretty cool, do you have anything referencing that in regards to java at all? Every where I'm looking is saying the cached memory and main memory are wrote differently. I'm just confused because otherwise what's the point of a volatile var?

Comment: @MatthewKerian It doesn't really relate to Java directly because Java is defined in terms of an abstract machine and it's the implementation's job to do whatever it needs to make the actual machine behave the way the language specification requires. The point of a `volatile` variable is to tell the implementation that it needs to do whatever it takes (which might be nothing or might be something complicated) to get the specific semantics defined for `volatile`. Often, it's just an optimization barrier. It gets very platform-specific though.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I don't feel like your response is good for the question itself then, I don't think he's asking about implementation details. I think he wants to know what java is doing under the hood. The fact that those volatile and synchronized blocks do still force write to memory is what I think the question should be about.

Comment: @MatthewKerian That's possible. But I think he really just wants to know how to use these things correctly in Java and what performance implications they're going to have. I don't think he really wants to know what goes under the hook, but just thought that he had to. I could be wrong though.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I am courious about "under the hood stuff" but as you correctly guessed I was asking about proper usage (the contract what does what) and performance implications. The "under the hood" is separate and I suppose much wider topic/question.